# slicing an array with offset and limit

Tags: python

i'm migrating some data from SqlAlchemy selects into a cache of item ids.

i'm trying to figure out the best way to handle migrating functions that have a limit and offset attached.

the code i have below works fine. my worry is that it takes 7 lines - and usually when something like this takes a few lines, it's because I'm not seeing something or there's something about Python that I forgot about or haven't learned yet.

```
def sampling( selection, offset=0 , limit=None ):
    if offset or limit:
        if limit is not None:
            limit = offset + limit        
        else:
            limit = len(selection)
        selection = selection[offset:limit]
    return selection

ids = range(1,100)
print sampling(ids,1,20)
print sampling(ids,10,20)
print sampling(ids,90)
print sampling(ids,90,300)
```

Answer (score 13):

The following should work:

```
def sampling(selection, offset=0, limit=None):
    return selection[offset:(limit + offset if limit is not None else None)]
```

This works for three reasons:

1. There is no need to check whether the offset is 0 (if it's 0, it starts from the beginning)
2. `selection[offset:None]` goes from `offset` to the end of the list
3. The ternary operator `(limit + offset if limit else None)` lets you use `limit + offset` if the limit is an integer, and `None` if it is not. (Notice that it doesn't matter if `limit + offset` is greater than the length of the list. `selection[10:100000000]` will default to going up to the end of the list).

Comment: `limit is not None` would avoid the corner case of `limit==0`, where your two functions differ.

Comment: So the basic logic is [offset:(offset+limit)]

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import islice
def sampling(selection, offset=0, limit=None):
    return islice(islice(selection, offset, None), limit)
```

or if you need a list instead of an iterable

```
def sampling(selection, offset=0, limit=None):
    return list(islice(islice(selection, offset, None), limit))
```